# c# Key Events Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf

**My question is:** Why is the KeyUp Event being called with the D key as shown below.

There seems to be no reason for this keyup event to be called. Is it something to do with an inability to handle multiple key events??

**Console Output (shows false keydown being called)**

```
Keydown: D     ---> D Key pressed and held on keyboard
Keyup: D       ---> D KEY NOT RELEASED ON KEYBOARD
Keydown: S     ---> S Key pressed on keyboard
Keydown: D     ---> D Key being held as before (repeat calls should be omitted in this)
Keyup: S       ---> S Released on keyboard
Keyup: D       ---> D Released on keyboard
```

Here is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    ...
    Closing="Window_Closing"    

    Title="MainWindow" Height="588" Width="816"
    KeyDown="Event_KeyDown"
    KeyUp="Event_KeyUp"
    MouseLeftButtonDown= "Event_MouseDown" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
```

**KeyDown:**

```
public void Event_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inGame)
        {
            if (!e.IsRepeat) { System.Console.WriteLine("Keydown: " + e.Key.ToString()); }
            if (e.Key == Key.D || e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                player.right = true;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.A || e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                player.left = true;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.W || e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                player.jump();
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                flying = true;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.S)
            {
                player.falling = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**KeyUp:**

```
public void Event_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inGame)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Keyup: " + e.Key.ToString());
            if (e.Key == Key.S)
            {
                player.falling = false;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.D)
            {
                player.right = false;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.A || e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                player.left = false;
            }
             if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                flying = false;
            }
              if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                inGame = false;
                mainMenu = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is this part? `The console during bug`. Is it what happens or what you expect to happen?.

Comment: Updated the code, the console showed what actually happens, not what I expect to happen

Comment: The behavior you describe is not plausible in just the small amount of code you've provided here. Assuming you really are pressing the keys exactly as you state and you are doing nothing else, then: either your keyboard is defective, you've got some kind of driver or other keyboard input TSR running, or you've got some other code in your program that is interfering with the correct observation and handling of the key events. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.